# if $f(x,y)=0$. then $f_x(x,y)=f_y(x,y)=0$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ if real polynomial and $f(x,y)=0$.

It is true that, $f_x(x,y)=f_y(x,y)=0$?

Comment: My inclination is to say this is true because $f(x,y)$ is already constant and $0$. So partial derivatives would still yield $0$.

Comment: I think OP intended $f$ as a function of $x,y$ with the hypothesis is that $f(a,b)=0$, then asks if $f_x (a,b) = f_y (a,b) = 0$. The notation could use some work, I guess. A lot of work.

Comment: If $f(x,y) = 0$, then it is true that the partial derivatives are 0. But
 if $f(x_0,y_0) = 0$, it is not necessary true that its partial derivatives at that points are 0. $(x_0,y_0)$ is just a fixed point.